# How do I match up USER table and USERINFO table records one for one?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, innodb, php-7.2

I have a UserLogin table for users to login with username and password. I also have a UserInfo table containing Address, Phone Numbers, and information in 30 other columns.

When a user is created in the UserLogin table, I want to match up their UserLogin row with a row in the UserInfo table so that I can store user details in the UserInfo table. My goal is to have these tables have Primary Key IDs that match so that the UserLoginID = '2493' and UserInfoID = '2493'. That way, the tables will match row for row, one for one, in efforts that the user profile information will always marry up with their UserLogin account.

What is the best way (best practices) to accomplish this?

**UserLogin Table**

 - userID (Primary Key)(Auto_Increment)
 - username
 - password
 - email
 - useraccess

**UserInfo Table**

 - UserInfoID (Primary Key)(Auto_Increment)
 - FirstName
 - LastName
 - Address
 - PhoneNumber

When a new UserID is created, I want a UserInfoID to also be created and tied to the UserID so that when they login and enter in their Profile details, it will enter into the UserInfo table.

***Thx to Vintage Coders! This is what I ended up w/ and it works flawlessly:***

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO UserLogin (username,password,email) 
VALUES (:username, :password, :email)');

$stmt->execute(array(
':username' => $username, 
':password' => $hashedpassword, 
':email' => $email  ));

$id = $db->lastInsertId('adminID');

include('includes/database.php');

$FirstName=$_POST['FirstName']; 
$LastName=$_POST['LastName'];

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO UserInfo(UserInfoID, FirstName, LastName) 
VALUES ('$id', '$FirstName', '$LastName')");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1) When you insert the record of first table then you can get the last inserted id and you save your second table UserInfoID as getting from the first table.

2) You can create a new field in the second table i.e related to the first table (userid). and when you insert the record in the second table ,you can insert last inserted id of the first table add in second table column i.e (userid).
The formula is :

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Thanks! This works flawlessly. Only difference is that I used mysqli. Other than that, it is working like a charm. =)

Answer (score 0):

There are some simple ways to address this:

- Combine the two tables into one.
- Add userID field into the UserInfo table.  (Be careful not to create more than one UserInfo record with the same userID value, perhaps make that column unique for safety's sake).

I can't see any value in adding the UserInfoID field into the users table.  Once you have the user's userID you can easily locate the UserInfo record.